# ID session management in Android for web-services

Tags: java, android, web-services, session, android-ksoap2

I'm creating an app that interacts with SOAP web-services to get data from the database.
When the user successfully logins in by passing the username and password via web-services , a unique session ID to that user is given. This session ID will be needed later on in other activities to call web-services methods. My question is, how can I pass on that session ID to the next activity when its needed and maintain it until the user logs out.
For example:
This is a web-service method, that requires the SID(session id) to be passed on, how can i take that session ID that was giving to me when i logged in, and use it for this method

```
-<element name="createAttachment">


-<complexType>


-<sequence>

<element name="sid" type="xsd:int"/>

<element name="repositoryHandle" type="xsd:string"/>

<element name="objectHandle" type="xsd:string"/>

<element name="description" type="xsd:string"/>

<element name="fileName" type="xsd:string"/>

</sequence>

</complexType>

</element>
```

Thats my login.java . I can login successfully and i get a session id

```
public class Login extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener  {

    private static final String NAMESPACE = "***";
    private static final String URL = ***"; 
    private static final String METHOD_NAME = "login";
    private static final String SOAP_ACTION =  NAMESPACE + "/" + METHOD_NAME; //in wsdl it's nothing


    EditText usersusername, userspassword;
    Button LB;



    @Override 


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login); 
         LB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginbutton);
         LB.setOnClickListener(this);
         usersusername = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editusername);
         userspassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editpassword);




    }

    public void onClick(View view){

    switch (view.getId()){

    case R.id.loginbutton:
    new LongOperation().execute("");

    break;


    }
    }


    private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{ 
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

           SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
           usersusername = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editusername);
           userspassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editpassword);
           String user_Name = usersusername.getText().toString();
           String user_Password = userspassword.getText().toString();


           PropertyInfo unameProp =new PropertyInfo();
           unameProp.setName("userName");//Define the variable name in the web service method
           unameProp.setValue(user_Name);//set value for userName variable
           unameProp.setType(String.class);//Define the type of the variable
           request.addProperty("username",user_Name);//Pass properties to the variable

           PropertyInfo passwordProp =new PropertyInfo();
           passwordProp.setName("password");
           passwordProp.setValue(user_Password);
           passwordProp.setType(String.class);
           request.addProperty(passwordProp);

           SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11); // Declare the version of the soap request
           envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

           try {
                HttpTransportSE aht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);


                aht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);  //this is the actual part that calls the web service
                SoapPrimitive result =(SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
                String Something = result.toString(); // Result string
                System.out.println(Something);
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(Something)) 
                {

                   Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this,Dashboard.class);
                   intent.putExtra("username",usersusername.getText().toString());
                   startActivity(intent);

           }
           }
           catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace(); 
           }



            return null; 

        } // closing bracket of do in background
        @Override
                // show dialog and prepare the fields for retry 


            }
        }  

    } // closing bracket of long operation  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can save sessionID in shared preferences and on logout remove the sessionID from shared preferences.
refer to this link for
[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values)